# Why is my container not starting on Google Compute Engine VM?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run a batch job on a VM preemptible on GCP.

My container does not seem to be starting. This is the log when i am connecting wia ssh on the VM.

Any suggestion or observation would be much appreciated !

[image]

> #########################[ Error ]#########################   #  The
> startup agent encountered errors. Your container   #   #  was not
> started. To inspect the agent's logs use       #   #  'sudo journalctl
> -u konlet-startup' command.           #   ###########################################################
> jackychan145@instanceapptraining ~ $ sudo journalctl -u
> 2021/10/24 00:37:54 Pulling
> image: 'gcr.io/local-*traffic*-p> Oct 24 00:37:55 instanceapptraining
> konlet-startup[457]: 2021/10/24 00:37:55 Error: Failed to start
> container: Erro> Oct 24 00:37:55 instanceapptraining
> konlet-startup[457]: 2021/10/24 00:37:55 Saving welcome script to
> profile.d Oct 24 00:37:55 instanceapptraining systemd[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp0u8.png):
> konlet-startup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/>
> Oct 24 00:37:55 instanceapptraining systemd[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp0u8.png):
> konlet-startup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> instanceapptraining konlet-startup[79011]: 2021/10/24 09:19:45 E
> rror: Failed to start container: Error response from daemon:
> {"message":"unautho
> rized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this
> operation, and you
> may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the
> steps in:
> [https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication"}](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication%22%7D)
> instanceapptraining konlet-startup[79011]: 2021/10/24 09:19:45 E
> rror: Failed to start container: Error response from daemon:
> {"message":"unautho
> rized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this
> operation, and you
> may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the
> steps in:
> [https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication"}](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication%22%7D)

Using this script :

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/local-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/apptraining', '.']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["push", "gcr.io/local-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/apptraining"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['compute', 'instances', 'create-with-container', 'instanceapptraining', '--machine-type=n1-standard-1', '--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore','--zone=us-central1-a', '--preemptible', '--container-image=gcr.io/local-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/apptraining:latest']
```

Comment: 1) Are you using Compute Engine or Compute Engine Container Optimized OS? 2) Edit your logs to be separate lines, it is currently one big line which makes it hard to read. 3) SSH into your instance and start the container manually. What error is reported? Your logs do not show what the error is.

Comment: thanks for your anwer . i'm trying to get the full ine but the logs are truncated

Answer (score 1):

By adding the following scope in my yaml file fixes the issue :

```
'--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/source.full_control,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/source.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly'
```

Comment: The correct/better solution is to only add the scope **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform** instead of your list.